# Passing an argument to call-process on cmdproxy

Tags: windows, shell, emacs, cmd, escaping

Some Emacs packages (for example AUCTeX) pass a user specified shell command to the shell by:

```
(call-process shell-file-name nil 0 nil shell-command-switch the-user-specified-command)
```

which in case of MS Windows is usually equivalent to:

```
(call-process "cmdproxy" nil 0 nil "-c" the-user-specified-command)
```

How should I escape characters if I want to pass this shell command:

```
"print arg.py" "11 11" "22 22"
```

which runs a script (with a space in its basename `print arg.py`) with two arguments `11 11` and `22 22`?

In the following call, cmdproxy just says `Unable to initialize device PRN`.

```
(call-process "cmdproxy"
              nil "foo" nil
              "-c"
              "\"print arg.py\" \"11 11\" \"22 22\"")
```

For the following call, it says `error: no program name specified.`

```
(call-process "cmdproxy"
              nil "foo" nil
              "-c"
              "\"\"print arg.py\"\" \"\"11 11\"\" \"\"22 22\"\"")
```

For the following, it says `'\"print arg.py\"' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

```
(call-process "cmdproxy"
              nil "foo" nil
              "-c"
              "\\\"print arg.py\\\" \\\"11 11\\\" \\\"22 22\\\"")
```

On the other hand, the following call succeeds in running the script with arguments `11 11` and `22 22`.

```
(setenv "ABC" "\"print arg.py\" \"11 11\" \"22 22\"")
(call-process "cmdproxy"
              nil "foo" nil
              "-c"
              "%ABC%")
```

That can be a good workaround but it doesn't tell how to escape characters.

Contents of the script file `print arg.py`, for those who want to test:

```
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print "start"
    for arg in sys.argv[1:]:
        print "(" + arg + ")"
    print "end"
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you don't need a shell for that: just do `(call-process "print arg.py" nil "foo" nil "11 11" "22 22")`.

Comment: That requires modifying the code of the package. Users of the package can only change the user option the-user-specified-command or make a feature request for a way around. AUCTeX does provide a way around, but there may be other packages that don't.

Answer (score 0):

Escape the space in the command name with backslash and put the arguments into single quotes:

```
(call-process "cmdproxy"
          nil "foo" nil
          "-c"
          "print\ arg.py '11 11' '22 22'")
```

Comment: With `"print\ arg.py '11 11' '22 22'"`, it says `'printarg.py' is not recognized ...`. With `"print\\ arg.py '11 11' '22 22'"`, it says `'print\' is not recognized ...`.

Comment: I tested this with regular executable which has a space in its name. Since you have a python script, there is a python interpreter that gets called by cmdproxy with your script as an argument. Try putting the 'print arg.py' in single quotes as well. Which python do you have?

Comment: My python is installed to `C:\Python27` but I am not sure why the path to the Python executable would matter as the error message seems to be printed by cmd or cmdproxy. The full error message was `'printarg.py' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`  With `"'print arg.py' '11 11' '22 22'"`, the error message is `''print' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`